# How to make non editable form or textfield after click button Submit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
                        <form [formGroup]="calculateForm">
                          
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <p for="inputFrom" class="col-sm-4">Distance traveled(km):</p>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                              <input type="text" numbersOnly class="form-control form-control-md"
                                formControlName="distance">
                            </div>
                          </div>

                     
                                <button type="button" (click)="calculate()" class="btn btn-success">{{'Save | translate }}</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <br>
                        </form>
```

I want after fill the form and click Save button, the form will be non editable, only can see. Just one time fill in.I tried readonly but it for before click Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable the form you can just call the `this.calculateForm.disable()`. To do so for the save button as well use in your `function calculate` a flag to disable the button when it's clicked. First introduce a new variable containing a `boolean` named `isDisabled`. You can bind to the `disabled` attribute of the DOM element with binding syntax. `<button [disabled]="isDisabled" type="button" (click)="calculate()" class="btn btn-success">{{'Save | translate }}</button>` . Set the `isDisabled` variable in the `calculate function` to true and the button which is bind to the variable will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In your calculate method, or in another method triggered by clicking the Save button, call `this.calculateForm.disable()`.

To re enable the form, you can call it's `enable()` function.

You can also enable and disable individual controls.